# Find the variance of z=2x-3y

Tags: statistics

Find the variance of Z = 2x-3y. Assume X and Y are independent with X as Geometric with p = 1/2 and Y as Geometric with p = 1/3.

I know how to find the variance for each Geometric distribution using the formula:
$$\sigma^{2}=\frac{1-p}{p^{2}}$$
Using the above, I got 2 for Geometric with p = 1/2 and 6 for Geometric with p = 1/3. My question is how do I use this information to find the correct value for Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[Z] = 2\mathbb{E}[X] - 3\mathbb{E}[Y]$$ (linearity of expectation)

$$\mathbb{E}[Z^2] = 4\mathbb{E}[X^2] + 9\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - 12\mathbb{E}[XY] = 4\mathbb{E}[X^2] + 9\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - 12\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$$ (independence)

You already know how to compute the mean and second moment for $X$ and $Y$. You can plug those into the above and compute $Var(Z) = \mathbb{E}[Z^2] - \mathbb{E}[Z]^2$.

Comment: So i understand the formula's above, but I seem to be having trouble wrapping my mind around the logic of calculating Var(Z). I worked out the formulas above with the given information and I got both E(Z^2) and E(Z)^2 to both be 25 so when I subtract them I am getting 0. Would this be correct or am I just missing something in the calculation?

Comment: Must be a calculation error. The only random variable with zero variance is one that is constant. Clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$You can do the question in the following way. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $2X$ and $-3Y$, so

$$\Var(2X-3Y)=\Var(2X)+\Var(-3Y)= 4\Var(X)+9\Var(Y).$$

(This is because the variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances. I also used the property $\Var(aZ)=a^2\Var(Z)$ for constants $a$.)

Substitute known values to finish.